# GCC entrypoint address

Tags: gcc, elf

I am compiling a very basic "hello world" program with gcc, with this command line:

```
gcc -m32 prog_cible.c -o prog_cible
```

I am very surprised of the entry point address:

```
readelf -h prog_cible
...
Entry point: 0x420
```

I have tunrned off alsr with this command:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

I think this cannot be the real entry point.
I suppose a base address is added to 0x420 ?
In the past, 10 years ago, readelf gave me the good entry point. What has changed since ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I think this cannot be the real entry point.

You are correct. Your `gcc` is likely configured to build `PIE` binaries by default. `PIE` binary is really a special form of a shared library.

If you look at the `type` of the binary (which `readelf -h` also printed), you'll see that it's a `DYN`, not `EXEC`.

You can disable `PIE` with `gcc -m32 -no-pie ...`, and then your entry point will look something like `0x8048420`.